# Why are flip-flops criss-crossed?

Tags: flipflop, memory, computers

I want to simulate how a computer works using logic gates. Right now I am trying to build the memory aspect of it.

After looking at various articles and books I see a lot of them using flip-flops/latches to build the memory and I was confused about how they arrived at the circuit diagram because I was used to deriving logic circuit diagrams from truth tables.

After doing some research, I have seen the two inverted gates and a feedback loop.

[image]

The And Or latch

[image]

Most times always settles back to the criss-cross flip flop.

This is what I mean when I ask why they are criss-crossed:

[image]

I haven't gotten a satisfactory knowledge of storing a one-bit data, this is why this is used, this why this is like this and so forth.

I know most of the intricacies will be on electronics, but I just to understand it.

Comment: What do you mean by "criss-cross"? The way a SR latch implemented with NAND or NOR gates is usually drawn?

Comment: Have you tried finding a different way to store a bit using only logic gates?

Comment: They criss-cross because we normally draw the gates with the inputs on the left and the outputs on the right. If you flip one of the gates around or place them one after the other, the criss-cross is eliminated, and the positive feedback loop becomes more obvious.

Comment: Yes @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine

Comment: @DaveTweed because I see a lot of explanations on the flip flop and I couldn’t understand why they had to cross it. I wanted to know if there where advantages/disadvantages to doing that.

Comment: Please I want to know why my question got a down vote

Comment: Several reasons probably. A flip flop is a very basic logic element and well described in lots of books and web sites. And you've asked additional questions that could also be answered by some basic research.

Comment: How flip-flops can be drawn in various different ways does not depend on what it does or how it works so those two concepts are not related and should be kept separate. And of course flip-flops are not the only way of storing bits, as there are various different types of memories. For example, bits have been stored as sound waves in mercury vapour in the early days of computing.

Comment: @UkpaUchechi Please describe what you mean by crisscrossed, some examples would help.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have done that, I hope the question is clearer.

Comment: Notice the flip flop has complimentary outputs while the others don't. Since you need to feed the output back to the input for memory, you end up criss crossing.

Comment: @Justme Not Hg vapor- [liquid mercury delay lines](https://www.computerhistory.org/revolution/memory-storage/8/309), also see [this](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/f7/97/cd/c2e4049f574d4d/US2629827.pdf) patent. Before my time.

Comment: All three circuits you've drawn are logically identical. The inverter loop is just a S-R latch with S=R=0.

Answer (score 9):

The criss-cross layout is simply a compact way of drawing the two inter-connected gates.

Since that drawing layout is compact and convenient, it has become a "standard" and easily recognized way to draw a flip-flop.

A further thought: the criss-cross arrangement implies to me that the two gates work together, while the horizontal arrangement in your second drawing implies the left gate does something, then feeds the result to the right gate - it doesn't "look like" the two gates work together.

Comment: the And or Or latch is defined as a form of flip flop. 
Does that mean that I can’t be used to store state if the gates are not working together?

Answer (score 7):

The circuits are exactly the same.
[image: criss-crossed]

Answer (score 5):

Elementary computer building blocks, like any circuits, were invented not so much in a logical way but rather through intuition, imagination and common sense. Then, they are used to build more complex logic circuits through formal methods. In essence, they are analog circuits that are forced to work as digital. So, normally they are digital but during the transition they act as analog.

There are many ways to store data. Most of them use all sorts of physical effects but here a "circuit way" of memorizing based on the principle of positive feedback is used. To understand how, let's look at a possible scenario for inventing this memory circuit.

## Building scenario

**1. A non-inverting amplifier without memory.** Logic gates are amplifiers... but amplifiers have no memory. For example, if we apply a voltage to the input of a non-inverting amplifier, a higher voltage with the same polarity will appear at the output. When we remove the input voltage, the output voltage will dissapear. How can we make it stay that way? How do we make the "forgetting" amplifier remember?

[image: Non-inverting amplifier_250]

**2. A non-inverting amplifier with memory.** The recipe is very simple - just connect its output to its input. Thus, the amplifier will produce its own input signal. The name of this trick is "positive feedback".

[image: Non-inverting amplifier with positive feedback_250]

**3. Cascaded inverting stages.** But in general, transistor amplifier stages are inverting. To make them non-inverting, we connect one after the other (cascade) two inverting stages. Indeed, there is another reason to do so, and that is to be able to toggle the circuit by two separate inputs.

[image: Cascaded inverting amplifiers_500]

**4. Symmetrically drawn circuit.** If we move one element over the other, we will get a beautiful symmetrically drawn circuit...

[image: SRAM cell_250]

**5. ... that can be simultaneously controlled on both sides (left and right).** This drawing is used in SRAM structures where this circuit acts as an elementary memory cell. Note that there are no additional inputs (the low-power circuit is "forcibly" controlled by many times more powerful bit lines).  This greatly simplifies the organization of memory.

[image: SRAM cell controlled_500]

**6. Cross-coupled pair.** When using this circuit as a latch (flip-flop), we add additional inputs to toggle it "gently". We prefer to draw the inputs on the left and the outputs on the right. For this purpose, we "twist" the circuit as the number "8" and name it *cross-coupled pair* (or, if you prefer, "criss-crossed").

[image: Latch_250]

So the answer to why this circuit is cross-coupled is simply, ***The circuit is cross-coupled because it is drawn cross-coupled.***

## Transistor version

If you really want to understand this circuit, I recommend you watch [my movie](https://photos.app.goo.gl/59vK5Yn5pwmvBhjr8) in which I build a latch with real transistors. These are two cascaded amplifier stages "common emitter" visualized with LEDs.

## Advantages

This "circuit way" of memorizing allows to read/write data at high speed. Another advantage is that the memory cell is implemented by conventional elements (logic gates).

## EDIT: Is it possible to implement flip-flops with AND or OR gates?

> you mentioned that they have to be inverters, what of the case of the And or Or latch that is not inverted

Your question is very relevant... and I had to think a little to find an answer...

In my opinion, the main reason that a flip-flop cannot be done with (two) non-inverting logic gates AND and OR is that it will not be able to change its state (the logic gates will be uncontrolled). Let's see it in a latch made by one AND...

[image: 1-AND latch]

... and made by two cascaded AND.

[image: 2-AND latch]

When it is implemented with inverting logic gates, for example NAND, they alternate - through one logic gate we can set it in "1" (by applying "0" to its second input) and it loses its control properties; then we can set it to "0" through the other logic gate (again, by applying "0" to its second input)... and again, it loses its control properties.

See also my [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/668256/61398) to a related [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/668101/61398) illustrated by CircuitLab simulations.

Comment: Thank you for your response, please I have to ask, for the positive feedback diagram if the circuit is off won’t the current still be lost regardless. Also for the two inverters can a buffer be used instead?

Comment: @Ukpa Uchechi, I guess your question is whether after turning off the power the circuit will return to its old state? If so, here is my answer: It usually returns to the same state it prefers;  ie, stored data is lost. This is the big disadvantage of RAM (as they say, it is a "volatile memory").

Comment: @Ukpa Uchechi, The two inverters can be anything as long as it amplifies (K > 1) and inverts.  As you can see in the movie above, I have used the simplest "common emitter" transistor amplifier stage. In flip-flops, we prefer to use inverting logic gates (NAND or NOR) with two inputs since the one input is used by the positive feedback and the other by the input signals; so there is not a conflict between voltages.

Comment: Thank you @Circuit fantasist for your answer, please I have a few questions
1) flip flops are bistable multivibrators which I understand is, that a single output can either be in an on-state(1) or off-state (0). is this correct?

2) I am thinking that when the state needs to change, it kind of flips the state of the two outputs that's why the outputs have to be in the inverse of each other.

3) you mentioned that they have to be inverters, what of  the case of the And or Or latch that is not inverted

Comment: I hope my questions are clear and make sense

Comment: @Ukpa Uchechi, Your question is very relevant... and I had to think a little to find an answer. In my opinion, the main reason that a flip-flop cannot be done with non-inverting logic gates AND and OR is that it will not be able to change its state (the logic gates will be uncontrolled). When it is implemented with inverting logic gates, for example NAND, they alternate - with one logic gate we can set it in "1" (by applying "0" to its second input) and it loses its control properties; then we can set it to "0" through the other logic gate (again, by applying "0" to its second input)...

Comment: ... and again, it loses its control properties... The strange thing is that such issues are not discussed in textbooks...

Comment: When you say it won’t be able to change its state I don’t get, so I simulated the And or Or latch and when both S and R = 0 it’s a hold state, when S = 1 and R = 0 it sets the state to 0 and when S = X and R = 1 it’s resets it to 1, plus also stated the logic gates will be uncontrolled

Comment: I worry I’m asking too many questions

Comment: @Ukpa Uchechi, This is a new idea for me and at the moment I can't explain it in a simple way. I need to think about it more. But it will be useful for you to try to understand it yourself through experiments and thinking. The questions are not a problem but tomorrow I am leaving in 10 days and I will not be able to answer during that time.

Comment: Alright thank you very much

Comment: @Ukpa Uchechi,  Well, when I come back, I will explain in detail why two logic gates are needed to make a flip-flop and why they must be inverting (in case you failed to understand it).

Comment: @Ukpa Uchechi, I have illustrated my explanations with two pictures. Do you hace some questions about why is not possible to make flip-flops with non-inverting gates?

Comment: You can make a flip-flop with non-inverting gates. Consider a non-inverting buffer with a resistor in the feedback path and a tri-state driver connected to the D input. Enabling the tri-state driver overdrives the resistor and changes the state of the latch. Discussions about using AND, OR, NAND, or NOR gates are moot because flip-flops are not really made that way anymore.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, You can also make a flip-flop in a similar way by a Schmitt trigger connecting its input through a resistor to a voltage between the two thresholds. You can toggle it by momentary connecting the trigger input (after the resistor) to ground or Vcc. "Discussions about using AND, OR, NAND, or NOR gates" are conceptual and because of that important.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, I have shown that the inputs of the conventional logic gates are "one-directional" and we can toggle the latch only in one direction. That is why, we need two inverting logic gates. The input of the Schmitt trigger is "bi-directional" and we can toggle the latch in both directions.

Comment: Regardless of what you have "shown", a fully functional flip-flop can be constructed from non-inverting CMOS logic. If you allow the addition of a feedback resistor then the flip-flop is also fully static. My objection is to your blanket misstatement that "is not possible to make flip-flops with non-inverting gates".

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, I mean non-inverting gates with conventional inputs. I wil give another example of a non-conventional control - SRAM cell, where the "decoupling" resistor is missed and the cell is brutally (directly) toggled by a powerful voltage source.

Comment: The principle of the flip-flop operation has been, is and will always be the same. It is based on two concepts - **positive feedback** and/or **hysteresis**.  That is what the OP needs to dig into... not specific implementation details that get old and change...

Comment: @ElliotAlderson why I ask if the outputs must invert is, study shows the d flip flip/jk flip flop is built to avoid this from happening

Comment: @UkpaUchechi Flip-flops were built from inverting gates like NAND and NOR a long time ago, but that is not how CMOS flip-flops are built. And it is possible to build flip-flops using non-inverting gates if the feedback path is weaker than the input path, or if there is no feedback at all. Hysteresis is not required. You would do well to search for "CMOS flip-flop" to see how things are done these days.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Okay thank you

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, Hysteresis is required when the latch has only one input and three input levels (thresholds, states) - LOW, HIGH and HIGH IMPEDANCE (disconnected, or between the two thresholds). This was [my favorite experiment](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Group_67b#Lab_4:_Endowing_circuits_with_memory) in Digital circuits laboratory. I am very interested in learning how to make a flip flop without feedback or hysteresis. Maybe this is a third (new for me) principle for making transistors memorize?

Comment: Your choice of language is inconsistent with the rest of industry so I don't think there is much point in continuing this thread. For example, "HIGH-IMPEDANCE" is not an "input level". Input levels are voltages, plain and simple.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, I meant my example above where the input of a Schmitt trigger is connected with a resistor to a voltage with a value between the trigger thresholds. So, if you disconnect the input (HIGH IMPEDANCE), this voltage will be applied through the resistor. OK, I  am also stopping because, as usual, conversations with you are fruitless and lead nowhere... All that remains is an unpleasant feeling...

Answer (score 5):

## All three circuits you've drawn are identical.

Really.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBMURo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. -> 2. Add two inverters in series to output of A1: those don't change anything.
2. -> 3. Merge A2 and D2 into a NOR AD3.
3. -> 4. Apply DeMorgan's identity to inverted inputs AND C3.
4. -> 7. Just rearrange things visually.

And:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUcBfl.png)</sup>

8. -> 9. We want an "idle" SR latch that just keeps its state. The S and R inputs are fixed to 0.
9. -> 10. An OR gate with one input set to zero is just a BUFFER gate. A NOR gate with one input zero is just a NOT gate.
10. -> 12. Rearrange things visually only.

The way I personally "derive" all latches is by starting with static circuits with feedback: just a bunch of buffers or inverters in line, with closed feedback. The buffers and inverters can be converted to AND/NAND respectively with the 2nd input set to "1", or OR/NOR respectively with the 2nd input set to "0". Then you can explore what functions those extra inputs have.

## Can a F/F be implemented with AND/OR gates only?

Sure!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv81t0.png)</sup>

It just happens that the RESET input has inverse (negative) logic. And it doesn't have a complementary output (~Q), just two Q outputs. That's all.

## TL;DR

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frOF8X.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer @Kuba hasn’t forgotten Monica, I have a question. 1) does that mean that the complementary output( Q = notQ) is not important,  but preferred for uniformity across design maybe. That’s why the nand/nor gate is mostly used.

Comment: @UkpaUchechi Well, it’s all besides the point, as real flip flops aren’t usually built out of gates, but out of transistor structures that work better than gates would. In other words: no gates are mostly used. The gate thing exists solely in textbooks and in simple circuits where someone had extra gates and needed a flip flop. These days a FF costs more to talk about than to put into a product whether it’s a discrete SOT part or in an PLD/FPGA or an ASIC.

Answer (score 1):

You can't analyse sequential logic (latch/flipflop) with truth table as it depend on logic state before.
What you need to know is, without any input, the output stay the same. When set input is high, output become high and vice versa.
As you says you want to simulate the computer system with logic gate. For memory part you should consider at as functional block. It too complicate to simulate flipflop with logic gate.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here is an example of a D flip-flop that does not **require** an inverting logic function and does not rely on hysteresis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr0REZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When CLK is high, the left latch is in the HOLD state...the feedback through MUX1 forms a positive feedback path that holds the current state. At the same time, the right latch is *transparent*, meaning that the value at the 1 input of MUX2 simply propagates out to the Q output.

When CLK is low the left latch is transparent but the right latch is in the hold state.

This is the classic behavior of the so-called "master-slave" flip-flop.

Now it is true that a CMOS implementation of a buffer will be constructed from two inverters, but the point here is that the flip-flop itself **does not depend** on an inverting logic function. The multiplexers are formed from two CMOS transmission gates, again a non-inverting function. Likewise, the circuit does not **depend** on hysteresis. The one characteristic that is critical is **propagation delay**...the delay through each latch must be greater than the transition time of the clock.

Comment: Just for completeness, there is an inverting logic gate inside the multiplexer:-)

Comment: @Circuit Not necessarily. The inversion of CLK can be done globally rather than inside the mux. Or the MUX could be made with one NMOS transistor (the '1' path) and one PMOS transistor (the '0' path). The point is that the function of the flip-flop does not **require** an inverting logic gate.

Comment: Of course muxes can use both P-element and N-element pass gates, so no inverters needed.